# mongodb find doc with matching values of element in object array

Tags: mongodb

I have a connection schema looking like this:

```
const FriendshipsSchema = new Schema({
  formed: Date
  members: [{
    _id: false,
    person: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }]
});
```

I'm trying to query all docs which their `members` array contain at least 2 objects of which their `person` field equals a given ID value.

As in:

```
formed: `some Date`
members: [
       {person: ObjectID_1, ..., ..., ...},
       {person: ObjectID_2, ..., ..., ...},
       {person: ObjectID_3, ..., ..., ...},
     ]
```

(Given values: `ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2`)

I am writing this after a deep dive into the query docs of mongodb site, though this kind of example was missing.

I suspect my query as of now is not remotely close to the proper usage,

But this is where I was heading...

```
Friendship.find({
    'members.person': { $in: [ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2] }
  })
```

Help much much appreciated

Comment: Try `Friendship.find({     'members.person': { $all: [ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2] }   })`

Comment: Post as answer and I'll accept. works =) thank you!